# A plus sign over log

Tags: math-operators

How can I put a plus sign over the function `\log`? I have to translate a doctoral dissertation and there is a symbol like that.

[image]

Comment: `\log\limits^{+}`

Comment: Can you point to a source/image?

Answer (score 3):

I'd raise less the + than with the simple `\overset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\logplus}{\overset{+}{\vphantom{g}\smash{\log}}}

\begin{document}

Comparison with the possible originally used construction
and the proposed one
\[
\overset{+}{\log}_{k+1}T
\qquad
\logplus_{k+1}T
\]
Now the formula; first in the probable original format
\[
\varrho^{(k)}(f):=
\varlimsup_{r\to\infty}\frac{\overset{+}{\log}_{k+1} T(r,f)}{\log r}
\]
and then in the proposed one
\[
\varrho^{(k)}(f)\coloneqq
\varlimsup_{r\to\infty}\frac{\logplus_{k+1} T(r,f)}{\log r}
\]
The $+$ sign is raised less as much, and the $T$ is correctly
spaced from the operator.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you like the + to be as high as in the original, just change the definition of `\logplus` into `\DeclareMathOperator{\logplus}{\overset{+}{\log}}`

Answer (score 1):

Using `\DeclareMathOperator{\plog}{}` with a stack.  The overset height can be adjusted with the `{1pt}` parameter.

```
\documentclass{article} % Adjust the font scale/size here
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\DeclareMathOperator{\plog}{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{1pt}{\log}{\scriptstyle+}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\varlimsup_{r\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\plog_{k+1}T(r,f)}{\log r}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you type `\log\limits^+`, then you will get what you want.

Comment: not with `amsmath` loaded, then you need more complicated `\mathop{\log}\limits^+`. Or you can redefine `\log` using this in preamble `\let\log\relax\DeclareMathOperator*{\log}{log}`, then it works as without amsmath.